# How are the ratios of successive values of the divisor function distributed?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

One motivation for this question is a paper by Erdos and Hall "Values of the divisor function on short intervals", in which the authors obtain the leading asymptotics

$$x(\log x)^{2(\sqrt 2-1)-\epsilon}\leq\sum_{n\leq x}\min{(d(n),d(n+1))}\leq x(\log x)^{2(\sqrt 2-1)}$$ and

$$\sum_{n\leq x}\max{(d(n),d(n+1),...,d(n+k-1)})\sim kx\log x.$$ In particular, it is possible that the answer to this question will lead to refinements of these bounds. It is also interesting simply as a curiosity.

Let $r(n)=d(n+1)/d(n)$. Heath-Brown proved that $r(n)=1$ for infinity many $n$, but I don't know how often this is expected to happen. Recent advances in knowledge of the gaps between primes suggests that small and large values are common.

> 1. What is known about the distribution of values of $r(n)$?
> 2. In particular, is it known that $r(n)$ is neither bounded above or below?

EDIT: $r(n)$ is neither bounded above or below - the proof is easy so I suppose that's not news though.

Comment: It might be interesting to study the ratio  $ \log d(n+1)/\log d(n) $ instead of  $ r(n) $ .

Answer (score 4):

Under GRH, Titchmarsh showed 1931 that $\sum_{p\leq x}\tau(p+a)\sim C(a)x$, where summation runs over primes only. 1963 Linnik proved the same unconditionally, hence there are many $n$ such that $d(n)=2$, $d(n+1)\gg\log n$ and similarly for $n-1$. Hence $r(n)$ is  quite often as big as $\log n$ and as small as $\frac{1}{\log n}$.

In general $r(n)$ is much closer to 1. Using some standard techniques in probabilistic number theory you can show that the joint distribution of $(\omega(n), \omega(n+1))$ is normal with mean and variance $\log\log x$, hence the distribution of $\log r(n)$ is normal with variance $2\log\log n$.

You can construct extreme values of $r(n)$ by taking an integer $n$ with many divisors, and look for a prime $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{n}$. By Heath-Browns version of Linnik's theorem, for $n>n_0$ such a prime $p$ exists satisfying $p\leq n^{5.5}$, hence $\max_{p\leq x} d(p+1)\geq \max_{n\leq x^{2/11}}d(n)$, thus for some small $c>0$ we have that $r(n)>e^{c\log n/\log\log n}$ has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: When you say $r(n)$ is much closer to $1$, do you know of some estimate that describes how much closer? I'm considering the average value of $e^{-|\log r(n)|/2}$, and my guess is also that this is $>1/2$, perhaps even $\sim \gamma$, based on calculations up to $10^8$.

Comment: $\log r(n)$ has a normal distribution with mean $2\log\log n$, so if $\omega(n)\rightarrow\infty$, then $|r(n)|<\omega(n)\sqrt{\log\log n}$ for a set of density 1. Note that the events $p|n$ and $p|n+1$ are negatively correlated, so as long as $\log\log n$ is not much larger than 1, $\omega(n)$ and $omega(n+1)$ do not look independent. Also $e^{-\sqrt{\log\log n}/2}$ looks pretty constant for all $n$ accessible by a computer.

Comment: Thank you , Jan-Christoph. Do you mean "$|\log r(n)|<\omega(n)\sqrt{\log\log n}$ for a set of density $1$? Would you clarify what you mean by "negatively correlated" and "do not look independent", please.

Comment: Of course I understand that the events $p|n$ and $p|(n+1)$ cannot both happen. But the number of primes less than $n^{1/\loglog n}$ is still large compared to $\log\log n$.

Comment: The expectation of $\omega(n)\omega(n+1)$ is $\sum_{p, q: p|n, q|n+1}1$ which is smaller than the expectation of $\omega(n)$ squared, since the latter contains an additional diagonal sum. However, the difference is smaller order than the non-diagonal main term, so  the joint distribution of $\omega(n)$ and $\omega(n+1)$ is asymptotically independent with normal marginal distributions (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem ). However, for small $x$ the sum of magnitude $\sum_p\frac{1}{p^2}$ is not negligible compared to $\log\log x$, so numerics can be misleading.